# Insert symbol into string C++

Tags: c++, string

I need to insert symbol '+' into string after its each five symbol.
st - the member of class String of type string

```
int i = 1;
int original_size = st.size;

int count = 0;
int j;
for (j = 0; j < st.size; j++)
{
    if (i % 5)
        count++;
}

while (st.size < original_size + count)
{
    if (i % 5)
    {   
        st.insert(i + 1, 1, '+');
        st.size++;
    }
    i++;
}

return st;
```

I got an error in this part of code. I think it is connected with conditions of of the while-cycle. Can you help me please how to do this right?

Comment: What is the error you got? Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: I can't spot any `std::string` or similar from your code??

Comment: Here's an easier way. Make a temp string large enough to hold st and st / 5  '+'s. Copy up to 5 chars from st. to temp, stopping when out of chars in st. Add a '+' to temp. Rinse. repeat. Then return temp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@AlexB's answer shows how to generate a new string with the resulting text.

That said, if your problem is to perform in-place insertions your code should look similar to this:

```
std::string st{ "abcdefghijk" };

for(auto i = 4; i != st.size(); i += 5) 
    st.insert(i+1, 1, '+'); // insert 1 character = '+' at position i

assert(st == "abcde+fghij+k");
```

Comment: Actually, my teacher told me it`s better to perform in-place insertions than to create another string and return this new string as a result. Thank you for your solution

Answer (score 3):

If I've understood you correctly then you want to insert a '+' character every 5 chars in the original string. One way to do this would be to create a temporary string and then reassign the original string:

```
std::string st("A test string with some chars");
std::string temp;

for (int i = 1; i <= st.size(); ++i)
{
    temp += st[i - 1];
    if (i % 5 == 0)
    {
        temp += '+';
    }
}
st = temp;
```

You'll notice I've started the loop at 1, this is to avoid the '+' being inserted on the first iteration (0%5==0).

Comment: Since you start with `i=1`, you need to use `i <= st.size()`. Otherwise, you will miss the last character.

Comment: You might get a signed-unsigned comparison warning from `i <= st.size()`.

Comment: Yes, you understood me correctly. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string InsertEveryNSymbols(const std::string & st, size_t n, char c)
{
    const size_t size(st.size());

    std::string result;
    result.reserve(size + size / n);
    for (size_t i(0); i != size; ++i)
    {
        result.push_back(st[i]);
        if (i % n == n - 1)
            result.push_back(c);
    }
    return result;
}
```

You don't need a loop to calculate the length of the resulting string. It's going to be simply `size + size / 5`. And doing multiple inserts makes it a quadratic-complexity algorithm when you can just as easily keep it linear.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing no one else has done, but eliminates the string resizing and the modulus and takes advantage of a few new and fun language features.

```
    std::string temp(st.length() + st.length()/5, '\0');
        // preallocate string to eliminate need for resizing.

    auto loc = temp.begin(); // iterator for temp string
    size_t count = 0;
    for (char ch: st) // iterate through source string
    {
        *loc++ = ch;
        if (--count == 0) // decrement and test for zero much faster than 
                          // modulus and test for zero
        {
            *loc++ = '+';
            count = 5; // even with this assignment
        }
    }
    st = temp;
```